# Calculus book with good explanation on squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, soft-question

I'm trying to learn squeeze theorem and it's quite difficult to get the concepts. Could anyone suggest some good books which explain this in depth, along with limits, continuity, etc?

So far, I have 2 books:

- Apostol - Mathematical Analysis(This looks tough, since I'm doing calculus.I'm not sure if this book is suitable for me at this time or I should get Apostol Calculus Vol 1.)
- Pure Mathematics - Hardy(I find this book nice so far, but I don't see a lot of graph and trigonometric functions in the book)

Please suggest some good books for calculus which go in depth which functions, limits, squeeze theorem, trig. functions, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Any calculus book explains this elementary theorem and you should practice by doing some problems.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Is it found in Apostol or Hardy? I'm still on the first chapter of both, but I went through all the pages to find it and couldn't. Or maybe it has a different name in those older books?

Comment: Sab: absolutely, if you like Apostol, start with *Calculus, Vol. 1* - NOT *Mathematical Analysis.*

Answer (score 2):

Try $Introduction\ to\ Real\ Analysis$ by Bartle & Sherbert or $Calculus$ by Michael Spivak. They are more elemntary than Apostol and have some very thorough explanations.